# Write a function to compute the product, e.g

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, return

Factorial of n is the product of the numbers from 1 to n.

```
factorial(1) → 1
factorial(4) → 24
factorial(13) → 6227020800
```

It must include: functions & arguments, return statement, use a loop

My try:

```
def factorial (n):
    n = 1
  
    for i in range (1,i):
        n = (i*n)

    return n
```

The program did not function properly, I thought that it will work based on my low level of experience

Comment: There are probably other problems, but the code you posted will crash because it is not indented properly.

Comment: What would you expect `for i in range (1,i)` to mean??

Comment: What error / output did you get and what did you want to get?

Comment: You are conflating a few things. First, don't change `n` that is your parameter and you should use it in the call to `range()`. Second, you need a new separate `total` variable to accumulate and return.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here, and it's not clear what you need help with exactly. To start, you're getting an `UnboundLocalError`, right? Do you understand what that means? Please read [ask], and you can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As @JonSG already pointed out, `n` is the **parameter** of the function (you can think of it as the input to the function). In the first line of your function, you change the value of the parameter `n` to `1`, meaning that **it doesn't matter what you pass in**, `n` will **always** be `1`. That means we need a local variable to store the result.

The code below shows you **one** way of implementing this in python. Note that I've created a second variable `fact` that stores the result.

Because the `range()` function is not inclusive (that means `range(1, 5)` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), we also have to add one to `n`.

```
def factorial(n):
    fact = 1 # we're creating this variable because we do not want to override n
  
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        fact = fact * i

    return fact
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as [builditluc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13576266) pointed out, your reusing `n` in your function. I completely missed that the first time, so, credit to him for spotting it. In my answer, I have renamed it to `x`.

Aside from that, the other problem you have is that Python's `range` function is not inclusive.

For instance, if I had `range(0, 5)`, it would iterate through five numbers, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, not six numbers, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

However, in a factorial, you are multiplying the integer as well as the lesser natural nonzero numbers. For instance, `5!` would be `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5`, not `1 * 2 * 3 * 4`.

Therefore, the correct code is as follows:

```py
def Factorial(x):
    n = 1
    for k in range(1, x + 1):
        n *= k
    return n
```

Additionally, you can slightly optimize the function by ranging not from `1` to `x + 1` but from `2` to `x + 1`, since multiplying by `1` does not change the original number. That would result in the following (slightly more optimized) code:

```py
def Factorial(x):
    n = 1
    for k in range(2, x + 1):
        n *= k
    return n
```

Note that I have simplified `n = k * n` to `n *= k` for readability, and that I have renamed `i` to `k` for no reason whatsoever.